# How to disable mounting of external drive at boot?

Tags: 11.04, boot, mount

Okay so I'm not exactly sure how it happened, but recently Ubuntu has been trying to mount an external hard drive that I usually have plugged in during boot. A message comes up during boot asking me to either wait, or press S to skip if the drive isn't plugged in when I start up my laptop.

My question is, how do I disable this drive from mounting at startup so I don't have to prompt Ubuntu to skip it at boot? I've looked up a couple other solutions to this, but all of them only seem to completely disable automounting, which would require me to manually mount the device when it's plugged in, which is not what I want. I just want to disable it from mounting at startup.

Comment: Are you sure the drive partitions are not in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: It's located there. I have this:

/dev/sdb1 /media/My\040Book ntfs

I assume I can just remove that line, but considering it's a read only file, it'd have to be done through the terminal, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a line in `/etc/fstab` related to that drive, remove it.

The file is read only for all users other that `root`.

To edit it use the command `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`, but make a copy of the file before editing, and do not touch nothing other than removing that line.

Answer (score 1):

To disable USB automount in Ubuntu 11.10 (with Gnome 3), launch `dconf-editor` (package `dconf-tools`) and uncheck the following entries:

- org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount
- org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open

Comment: If you have a *particular* drive you do not want to mount which was there when you installed the system and which your system is assuming is permanently connected, than editing `/etc/fstab` as the other answer suggests, is likely to work. If you want to have GNOME 3 stop automounting drives (like USB drives), then this is the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to prevent Ubuntu 11.10 from automounting media when it is plugged in or on booting. Neither of the above solutions work. Simply look in /media for all the automounted devices after trying the above solutions.